# Help identifying Lego bricks from a picture for a Geocache

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, bricks-and-pieces

I'd like to recreate a Lego design I've seen for an ammo can Geocache - its a box that opens with a hinged lid. I've found the parts for the handles (CLAMP 1X2) and hinge pieces (PLATE 1X2 W/SHAFT Ø3) on the top but I'm really struggling to find the large flat plat with hooks on the right side.

If you can help identify this particular piece I'd be grateful. If you have any idea what's on the right side too or any other bricks I need then suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you!

[image: Lego geocache ammo can]

Comment: Hi,  Where have you seen this build, and do they have photos of other angles?

Comment: As a fellow geocacher, I had to vote this up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The flat plate with hooks, on the left of the image, appears to be [Tile, Modified, 3 x 2 with 2 Open O clips](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30350b&name=Tile,%20Modified%202%20x%203%20with%202%20Open%20O%20Clips&category=%5BTile,%20Modified%5D#T=C)

Without an image from another angle, it is hard to tell what the connection on the other side might be - it could be [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 2 Open O Clips (Horizontal Grip)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60470b&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%202%20Open%20O%20Clips%20(Horizontal%20Grip)&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C), or perhaps a pair of [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on End (Horizontal Grip)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=63868&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Clip%20on%20End%20(Horizontal%20Grip)&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C), but it could equally be something *completely* different.

---

After a quick Reverse Image Search, I found this set for sale [on Geocaching.com](https://shop.geocaching.com/default/geocaching-supplies/build-your-own-ammo-can-brick-set.html) with images of other angles, including the Bag of Parts - and this model appears to use a pair of [LegoPlate, Modified 1 x 1 with Open O Clip (Horizontal Grip)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61252&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Open%20O%20Clip%20(Horizontal%20Grip)&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C), instead

Comment: Thank you very much, that's really helpful and given me lots of information to order what I need.